# cloudbalancing example of an optaplanner

Tags: drools-planner, optaplanner

I am new to the drool planner and trying to run cloudbalancing example, I copied code new java project(without swing) and try to run CloudBalancingApp.java then get following execption.

I copied following classes

- CloudBalancingApp.java
- AbstractPersistable.java
- CloudBalance.java
- CloudComputer.java
- CloudProcess.java
- CloudComputerStrengthComparator.java
- CloudProcessDifficultyComparator.java

When try to run CloudBalancingApp.java then get following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
No enum constant org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.ScoreDefinitionType.HARD_AND_SOFT :
No enum constant org.optaplanner.core.config.score.director.ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.ScoreDefinitionType.HARD_AND_SOFT
```

Answer (score 0):

`ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig.ScoreDefinitionType.HARD_AND_SOFT` comes from the jar optaplanner-core.

In 6.x, that variable was renamed from `HARD_AND_SOFT` to `HARD_SOFT`. See the [upgrade recipe](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/optaplanner/blob/master/optaplanner-distribution/src/main/assembly/filtered-resources/UpgradeFromPreviousVersionRecipe.txt). What version of optaplanner are you using?

Comment: I am using optaplanner-6.0.0,I did changed xml file and run program then get exception:- Exception in thread "main" com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field org.optaplanner.core.config.constructionheuristic.ConstructionHeuristicSolverPhaseConfig.constructionHeuristicPickEarlyType                                                                                                            Thanks for upgrade recipe.

Comment: Looks like the example code you copied from was from an earlier version. Compare with the example code from the later version. Anything `>= 6.0.0.CR1` is good. `6.0.0.CR4` should be out later this week.